# QGIS2WEB Error when exporting to Leaflet/OL3

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-plugins

I am having all kinds of problems with the QGIS plugins for exporting my map to Leaflet or OL3. Whenever I try to preview my project I just get a white screen with nothing. Then when I try to Export to Leaflet I get an error that doesn't allow me to do it saying:

```
TypeError: writeLeaflet() takes exactly 19 arguments (18 given)
```

I just don't know what to do, I have searched online to find help with this and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the code. In maindialog.py on Line 198 should be:

```
outputFile = writeLeaflet(self.iface, folder, 600, 400, 1, layers, visible, "", cluster, "", "", "", "", labels, 0, 0, json, params, popup)
```

Comment: I just installed it today VIA the Plugins tab in QGIS, but I will go and download it from their site, if available.

Comment: Okay, I am getting errors from all the OL and Leaflet plugins.... I jsut need to make this a webpage map for a presentation.....

Comment: Have you tried my fix?

Comment: About ready to, I keep getting a minidump crash so I just fresh installed, and where do I go change it from?

Comment: C:\Users\username\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2web

Comment: Just tried and now I am getting this error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'middle' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2):

Apologies that this was such a severe bug in qgis2web 0.14.0. I've fixed it as described by GreyHippo, and pushed qgis2web 0.14.1 as a GitHub release, and also onto the QGIS plugins repo - you should be able to update from within QGIS.